# variable scope inside of parametrized method - java generics

Tags: java, generics, collections, foreach, scope

why is it that inside this foreach loop, elem is not recognized as a Path, which it is, and I can only call Object methods on it?

```
public class TypeOption<Path> implements Option<Path> {

    @Override
    public void apply(String arg, Collection<Path> c) {
        for (Path elem : c) {
            if (Files.isExecutable(elem)) c.remove(elem);
        }
    }
}
```

this line

```
if (Files.isExecutable(elem)) c.remove(elem);
```

is causing the trouble, it says

```
The method isExecutable(java.nio.file.Path) in the type Files is not applicable for the arguments (Path)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `Path` is a type parameter here - you've declared a generic type, with `Path` as the type parameter. I suspect you *wanted:

```
public class TypeOption implements Option<Path> {
```

At that point, `Path` refers to the existing *type* called `Path`, and is used for the type *argument* to `Option<T>` (or whatever the type parameter is for `Option`).